# Remove unwrap calls from Options and Results without introducing doubly indented match statements

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

I'm trying to remove some unwrap functions from a project, but I can't figure out what the idiomatic version of this block would be::

```
let free_block = match util::find_free_block(size) {
    Some(block) => unsafe { (*block).split(size) },
    None        => unsafe { (*util::request_mem(size).unwrap()).split(size) }
};
```

without having a doubly indented match statement in the case of the `None` matching.

`util::request_mem(size)` returns a `Result<*mut T, i32>` and upon failure the `i32` value should be returned.

I understand there isn't a C-like equivalent of the arrow operator for dereferencing and calling a method on a raw pointer, which makes some of my code look awful but it's somewhat understandable why it isn't in the language.

Comment: We really like [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because it ensures that the answers are appropriate, instead of being wild guesses. Specifically here, it's unclear to me what the signature of `util::request_mem` is. From your comment it seems it returns some kind of `Option<T*>`, but I am not quite sure. Also, while it's nice to know that you would like to avoid `unwrap`, you are not specifying what should occur if `request_mem` returns `None`.

Comment: In addition, if you wrote the code *with* the "doubly indented match statement", that would be a way of showing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to convert the returned `Option` into a `Result`, then use methods like [`Result::or_else`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.or_else) to chain further work and macros like [`try!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.try!.html) to return early:

```
struct Thing;
impl Thing {
    fn split(&self, size: u8) -> bool { false }
}

fn find_free_block(size: u8) -> Option<*mut Thing> { None }
fn request_mem(size: u8) -> Result<*mut Thing, i32> { Err(1) }

fn the_answer(size: u8) -> Result<bool, i32> {
    let thing_ptr = try!(find_free_block(size).ok_or(0).or_else(|_| request_mem(size)));
    let thing = unsafe { &*thing_ptr }; 
    Ok(thing.split(size))
}

fn main() {}
```

Alternately:

```
fn the_answer(size: u8) -> Result<bool, i32> {
    find_free_block(size)
        .ok_or(0)
        .or_else(|_| request_mem(size))
        .map(|t| unsafe { &*t })
        .map(|t| t.split(size))
}
```

---

What would be pretty great is if something like this could work

```
fn the_answer(size: u8) -> Result<bool, i32> {
    find_free_block(size)
        .ok_or_maybe(|| request_mem(size))
        .map(|t| unsafe { &*t })
        .map(|t| t.split(size))
}
```

You could make this happen *right now* though:

```
trait Secret<T> {
    fn ok_or_maybe<E, F>(self, F) -> Result<T, E>
        where F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>;
}

impl<T> Secret<T> for Option<T> {
    fn ok_or_maybe<E, F>(self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
        where F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>
    {
        match self {
            Some(e) => Ok(e),
            None => f(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been wondering about the readability of the upcoming `?` but here I must admit... it takes a moment to understand the exact scope of `try!` with all those parentheses going on!

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah. I don't like that I had to make a "fake" error value of `0` and I don't like that the line is so long such that the `try` is hard to understand. I really want a method on `Option` that takes a `F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>`, but that seems pretty special-cased. I might normally split the `try` onto two lines as well...